# Diagonal heatmap with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I have a heatmap that I created from Pandas in this way:

```
tukey = tukey.set_index('index')
 
fix,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
ax.set_title(str(date)+' '+ str(hour)+':'+'00',fontsize=14)
heatmap_args = {'linewidths': 0.35, 'linecolor': '0.5', 'clip_on': False, 'square': True, 'cbar_ax_bbox': [0.75, 0.35, 0.04, 0.3]}
sp.sign_plot(tukey, **heatmap_args)
```

[image]

I have tried to do this with seaborn but I haven't gotten the desired output:

```
# Generate a mask for the upper triangle
mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(tukey, dtype=bool))
# Set up the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
# Generate a custom diverging colormap
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(230, 20, as_cmap=True)
# Draw the heatmap with the mask and correct aspect ratio
sns.heatmap(tukey, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, vmax=.3, center=0,
                square=True, linewidths=.5, cbar_kws={"shrink": .5})
```

[image]

As seen, it still shows square where it is supposed to be masked and obviously the cbar is different.

**My question is if there is any way to make it diagonal without using seaborn? Or at least just to get rid of the repeating part?**

Edit: sample of my dataframe (the tukey):

```
>>>     1_a    1_b      1_c     1_d      1_e    1_f
index
1_a     1.00    0.900  0.75      0.736    0.900  0.400
1_b     0.9000  1.000  0.72      0.715    0.900  0.508
1_c     0.756   0.342  1.000     0.005    0.124  0.034
1_d     0.736   0.715  0.900     1.000    0.081  0.030 
1_e     0.900   0.900  0.804     0.793    1.000  0.475
1_f     0.400   0.508  0.036     0.030    0.475  1.000
```

*I might have typo mistakes , the two diagonal sides suppose to be equal.

edit:
imports:

```
import scikit_posthocs as sp
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import scipy.stats as stats
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as stats

import seaborn as sns
```

Comment: can you share a sample of your data?

Comment: Can you try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  Does `sp` refer to [`scikit-posthocs`](https://github.com/maximtrp/scikit-posthocs). If your variable `tukey` is a 2D numpy array, you could try setting all unwanted values to `np.nan`.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander  I have added in the original post

Comment: @JohanC the tukey result is pandas dataframe

Comment: Did you try to set the unwanted elements to `np.nan`? Could you please add all the imports?

Comment: i'm not sure how to do that, can you give an example?

Comment: @JohanC the imports have been added to the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scikit_posthocs`' `sign_plot()` seems to create a `QuadMesh` (as does `sns.heatmap`). Setting an edge color to such a mesh will show horizontal and vertical lines for the full width and height of the mesh. To make the edges invisible in the "empty" region, they can be colored the same as the background (for example white).  Making individual cells invisible can be done by setting their values to `NaN` such as in the code below.

Removing a column and a row (e.g. `tukey.drop('1_f', axis=1, inplace=True)` and
`tukey.drop('1_a', axis=0, inplace=True)`), doesn't help to make the plot a bit smaller because `sign_plot` adds them back in automatically.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scikit_posthocs as sp
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

data_str = '''     1_a    1_b      1_c     1_d      1_e    1_f
1_a     1.00    0.900  0.75      0.736    0.900  0.400
1_b     0.9000  1.000  0.72      0.715    0.900  0.508
1_c     0.756   0.342  1.000     0.005    0.124  0.034
1_d     0.736   0.715  0.900     1.000    0.081  0.030 
1_e     0.900   0.900  0.804     0.793    1.000  0.475
1_f     0.400   0.508  0.036     0.030    0.475  1.000'''
tukey = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_str), delim_whitespace=True)

cols = tukey.columns
for i in range(len(cols)):
    for j in range(i, len(cols)):
        tukey.iloc[i, j] = np.nan

fix, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
heatmap_args = {'linewidths': 0.35, 'linecolor': 'white', 'clip_on': False, 'square': True,
                'cbar_ax_bbox': [0.75, 0.35, 0.04, 0.3]}
sp.sign_plot(tukey, **heatmap_args)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: thank you! great answer. little question - how did you replicate the same visualization as I have? (to be hoenst-  I am not sure where to define again the colores of the bar and it seems in my script and yours like the colores are not defined)

Comment: The colors and the legend text seem to be the defaults chosen by [`sign_plot`](https://scikit-posthocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/scikit_posthocs.sign_plot/). It can be changed by `sign_plot(...., cmap=[...])`. (These defaults could change in future versions of `scikit-posthocs`.)